# Example of a ring such that the projective variety satisfies the given condition

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm reading a paper and I came across the follwing statement:

> If we take any smooth surface $V \subset \mathbb{P}^3_{\mathbb{C}}$ of degree at least $2$ and containing a line, then $V$ is not factorial (since
> the line is a divisor which is not an integer multiple of the hyperplane section), but it is locally
> factorial because it is nonsingular.

I'm wondering what would be an example of a ring $R$ that would give me such a $V$? ($R$ being the homogeneous coordinate ring of $V$)

Comment: How about the projective variety with equation $x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2=0$?

Comment: To add somethig to Aphelli's correct answer. The key word to search is "Fermat Hypersurface" they give smooth hypersurfaces of any degree in any dimension of Projective space.